# How does a Unix computer physically know the time since Epoch?

Tags: unix, epoch

I get that the calculation for time on a Unix system is the current time minus Epoch, but how does the physical computer know when Epoch was? You can't really hard code the starting time because hardware is made at different times.

I figure you could have a source of truth that could be accessible on the internet, but that would mean offline computers would never know what time it is.

Comment: It's just like any other clock: you have to set it to the correct time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Computers have a built-in (battery powered) clock that the user can set.

Time is synchronized over the internet (see [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol)), but offline computers simply use their built-in clock (which usually starts to drift away from real time at some point and has to be adjusted every so often).